# python 3.7 logging problem when enabling logging.propagate

Tags: python, logging

I created my logger and tried to add handlers.

```
import logging
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, splitext


def BuildLogger(sourcePath):  #, logPath=None):
    srcBasename = basename(sourcePath)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # Must have to see DEBUG/INFO at all
    logger = logging.getLogger(srcBasename)
    logger.propagate = False  # Must remove under py3.7, but keep for earlier versions to see logger message.

    # Avoid duplicated logs caused by duplicated handlers each time we create logger from a different module.
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        return logger

    # Console log is for end-users: no debug messages.
    consoleHanlder = logging.StreamHandler()
    consoleHanlder.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    consoleHanlder.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(_name)s: %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(consoleHanlder)

    return logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylogger = BuildLogger(__file__)
    mylogger.info('hello')
```

However, this code raises `KeyError` whenever logging with my logger.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1034, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 880, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 622, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 591, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 433, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: '_name'
Call stack:
  File "/Users/kakyo/Desktop/0.Dev/playground/python/tkinter/logging_bug.py", line 25, in <module>
    mylogger.info('hello')
Message: 'hello'
Arguments: ()
```

I traced it down to in `BuildLogger()` where I did the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(srcBasename)
logger.propagate = False
```

As soon as I commented out the `logger.propagate` line, the problem disappeared.

This problem seems to only happen with Python 3.7. I didn't have this in Python 3.6. In fact, I needed that line to show anything in my logger file at all.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - can you provide an [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Please see my updated question.

Comment: Try to change `%(_name)s` to `%(name)s`. Note that a leading underscore means that something is **private**, i.e. subject to change at any version change, including bugfix release. If the code works in python<3.7 it's just by accident.

Comment: @Bakuriu You are right. Just did and fixed it. I should've stayed calm and pinned it down to the formatting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing an undefined attribute in your formatter, `_name` does not exist you have to use `name`:

```
logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(message)s')
```

If you look carefully at the error message it is telling you:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1034, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 880, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 622, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 591, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 433, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: '_name'
Call stack:
  File "/Users/kakyo/Desktop/0.Dev/playground/python/tkinter/logging_bug.py", line 25, in 
    mylogger.info('hello')
Message: 'hello'
Arguments: ()
```